# Tell the Source of a Print Output in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I'm getting `0.0` printed repeatedly in my debug output area. It prints it maybe about every 0.5 seconds or so. I've been trying to find where this is coming from for quite some time and I cannot seem to find it. Is there any way to see where in my code this is being printed? Here's an image of what is happening:

[image: 0.0 being printed in debut output]

Comment: Start by searching for `print` or `NSLog` in your code.

Comment: @rmaddy I did that but I got 1100 results. I have pod files etc that print stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to find this is to set a symbolic breakpoint on the symbol `print` and then run your app. When any code in your app attempts to call `print`, the debugger will stop within the assembly code from the `print` function. Look at the stack trace in the debugger to see what is calling `print`. Then click the "step out" button in the debugger to finish that call to `print` and see if `0.0` appears in the console. If it does then that `print` is probably your issue.

It's possible the output is not using `print`. It could be `NSLog` or `OSLog`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It ended up being that I had a timer in the background that I accidentally had started whenever the view loads and I must have been printing to test something and I just neglect to remove it. But thanks for the help because without you telling me how to do that, I would've probably never have found that!